# Removing duplicates using Set in Javascript

Tags: javascript, duplicates, set

I'm struggling with something that should be very simple. I have an array of objects. I need to remove duplicate from this array based on the `id` property. So I want to create a `Set` containing my ids, like this:

```js
let myArray = [{
    id: 10,
    other: "bla"
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    other: "meh"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    other: "bla"
  }
]

let indexes = new Set();
myArray.forEach(a => indexes.add(a.id));
console.log('indexes list', indexes)
```

But `indexes` is always empty. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

EDIT: I chose @Hyyan Abo Fakher's as correct answer because he was right, but the suggestion in @bambam comment was a great solution to the whole problem. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Which browser and version are you using? Try `console.log(Array.from(indexes))` Anyways. Just using reduce will be easier `const unique = arr.reduce((a,b) =>
    a.find(({id}) => id === b.id) ? a : a.concat(b)
, []);`

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you sure your `this.myArray` isn't empty?

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array 
Nice solution: Use the ECMA6 Set

Comment: Your code works. why are using this.myArray 
Share complete snippit

Comment: I suspect OP has realised their mistake and populated `this.myArray`, then found that the code works.

Comment: @Archer: yeah, hate those MIA OPs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**But indexes is always empty. What am I doing wrong?**

Your code is completely functional, the issue seems to come from the browser console itself, you expect that printing the `set` to the console will print the items of the set as in arrays but in fact, the browser will print only the object instance

Running your code on StackOverflow will print `indexes list {}`, but in fact, the browser console printed something else.

[image]

To make sure the list is not empty use the [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size) property

```js
let myArray = [{
    id: 10,
    other: "bla"
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    other: "meh"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    other: "bla"
  }
]

let indexes = new Set();
myArray.forEach(a => indexes.add(a.id));
console.log('indexes list', indexes.size)
```

To loop over the set you need to use `for ... of`

```js
let myArray = [{
    id: 10,
    other: "bla"
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    other: "meh"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    other: "bla"
  }
]

let indexes = new Set();
myArray.forEach(a => indexes.add(a.id));
for (let item of indexes) console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use `filter` method with `Set` to create new array of unique objects by `id`.

```js
const data = [{id: 10, other: "bla"},{id: 15, other: "meh"},{id: 10, other: "bla"}]

let result = data.filter(function({id}) {
  return !this.has(id) && this.add(id);
}, new Set)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Really nice approach!

Comment: @Leonid Pyrlia Thank you.

Comment: I like this but did not work for me... Trying to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You may check if the set has the ID, and if its not, then push the element to a new array. The final array will have the unique elements.

```js
var source = [
  {id: 10, other: "bla"},
  {id: 15, other: "meh"},
  {id: 10, other: "bla"}
];

var set = new Set();
var result = [];

source.forEach(item => {
  if (!set.has(item.id)) {
    set.add(item.id);
    result.push(item);
  }
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why push to a new array when you can just use the set?

Comment: @Barmar -- The set only contains the IDs of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Simply we can use arrays to resolve this issue with help of loop. like below:

```
var b = [];
a.forEach(function(index){
   if(b[index.id]==undefined){
       b[index.id] = index.other;
   }
});
console.log(b);
```

Here a is the original source array.

Comment: Why are you assigning to `b[index.id]` twice?

Comment: initially b[index.id] will be undefined, so it should be initiated before adding some values into it.

Comment: @BannarisamyShanmugam: but you're not adding any values to it.

Comment: You don't need to create a property or initialise anything.  You can just get rid of `b[index.id] = "";` as it is not required at all.

Comment: @Archer, You are right. I dont need to initiate it. Thanks